# ast.literal_eval throwing ValueError

Tags: python, json, string, literals

`ast.literal_eval` is throwing `ValueError: malformed string` for the following JSON.
I am unable to spot what the error is. I used online JSON validators, all mention that this a valid JSON.

Can someone help me spot the error with this string?

```
{
    "business_id": "Iu-oeVzv8ZgP18NIB0UMqg",
    "full_address": "3320 S Hill St,South East LA,Los Angeles, CA 90007",
    "schools": [
        "University of Southern California"
    ],
    "open": true,
    "categories": [
        "Medical Centers",
        "Health and Medical"
    ],
    "photo_url": "http://s3-media1.ak.yelpcdn.com/bphoto/SdUWxREuWuPvvot6faxfXg/ms.jpg",
    "city": "Los Angeles",
    "review_count": 2,
    "name": "Southern California Medical Group",
    "neighborhoods": [
        "South East LA"
    ],
    "url": "http://www.yelp.com/biz/southern-california-medical-group-los-angeles",
    "longitude": -118.274281,
    "state": "CA",
    "stars": 3.5,
    "latitude": 34.01971,
    "type": "business"
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`true` is an invalid literal in Python:

```
In [2]: ast.literal_eval('true')
ValueError: malformed node or string: <_ast.Name object at 0x7f32a096d550>
```

Use [`json`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) module (specifically [`json.loads`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads)) when you need to deserialize a JSON document.

Comment: This is right. true and false are invalid in Literal Eval. Once I replaced those with proper strings it worked.

Answer (score 3):

You're using the wrong tool for the job here - [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) is intended for parsing *python literals* from strings into python objects.   It is not intended for loading data from serialised JSON into python (although it may also work for that in a subset of cases, because serialised json format happens to overlap with python syntax some of the time).

Perhaps you were you looking for [`json.loads`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html)?

Comment: The complexity of the inputs supported by `ast.literal_eval` and `json.loads` are roughly the same. It's not like `ast.literal_eval` is restricted to single tokens or even any fixed level of nesting. The important thing is that they're not the same format.